# why listview empty when called in new activity

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

In my main activity I open up a new activity (called speisekarte) which only displays a listview. I do load data into it but still the listview doesn't show anything.

I tried the listview part in a seperate project (meaning speisekarte is the main activity) where everything works as planned. So how do I get it to work properly as part of the actual project?

Main Activity where speisekarte is called:

```
bt_hungrig.setOnClickListener {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_speisekarte)
        }
```

oncreate of speisekarte:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speisekarte)

        read_json()
        listing()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you share some more code?

You should try doing that with `Intent`, like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity_speisekarte.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And are you passing data for ListView from your `MainActivity`?
If so, the you will also have to use: `intent.putExtra()` method to pass data for ListView, so that `activity_speisekarte` can use the data for ListView.

I am new to StackOverflow, so pardon me if I get anything wrong.

Comment: I'm not passing any data from the `MainActivity`.Tried it with `Intent` and now it works, thank you! What's the difference though? Seems like `setContentView` just loads the design etc. before runtime

Comment: And talking about the difference, here's it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898355